# Expose GRPC service methods with a different port for each method and not with one port for the whole application

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, microservices, grpc, grpc-java

```
@GRpcService
public class GRPCServiceImpl extends Grpc.ImplBase {

    @Override
    public void updateDetail(UpdateDetail.UpdateDetailRequest request, StreamObserver<UpdateDetail.UpdateDetailResponse> responseObserver) {
    
    }

    @Override
    public void profileUpdate(Update.UpdateRequest request, StreamObserver<Update.UpdateResponse> responseObserver) {
      
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Update.UpdateRequest request, StreamObserver<Update.UpdateResponse> responseObserver) {

    
}
```

In my spring-boot application, I have class and methods like the above. There are a few methods. This service is exposed with default port 6565. And with the call to 6565 port, all those methods are executing. I need these methods to expose with a port for each method because coming requests are directed to different ports which cannot be changed. So different methods should be listening with different ports. I cannot have few applications for each method because those methods belong to related tasks.

Currently, I am using the following dependency,

```
<dependency>
<groupId>io.github.lognet</groupId>
<artifactId>grpc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I heard this method expose thing can be done using apache camel. Is there any other way to do this with keeping the above dependency? or any other ways I can achieve this ?. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have 3 gRPC methods which you want to expose in 3 different ports.

The best way is to:

1. Separate out 3 methods to 3 protos. (1 method per proto)
2. Now you can start each of the method as an independent service / thread running on different ports.

[Official Java gRPC Docummentation](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/quickstart/).

> I am telling this strategy in context of python, but should work for any other language too.

Comment: I cannot find a way to start each of the methods as an independent service. In my spring-boot application, there is one JAR file creating

Comment: Sorry @chad, I don't know Java. But I strongly believe you can write something in your program that can start multiple threads. Where each thread can start different gRPC method, over different ports. This official JAVA GRPC documentation can get you started --> https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/quickstart/